# *ngFor with default image

Tags: angular, typescript

I created a table that loads products and the corresponding image of that same product.

However, when a product is created but has no associated image, I put a default image on it.

The problem is that the default image is appearing to me + the image space as failed ... when I really just want to have the default image.

Does anyone know why this happens?

[image: Imag]

**HTML**

```
<table class = "gfg" *ngFor="let product of products; let  a = index;"> 
  <tr> 
      <td class = "geeks">
          <div *ngIf="imagMap.get(product.id) == null">
              <img src="./assets/semimagem.png" class="imgTable img-fluid" alt="">
            </div>
        <img [src]="imagMap.get(product.id)" class="imgTable img-fluid">
      </td> 
  </tr> 
</table>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please read up on how to use [ngIf](https://angular.io/api/common/NgIf) it's the building blocks of Angular and represents basic logic for your template.

You can use [ngContainer](https://angular.io/guide/structural-directives#ng-container-to-the-rescue) instead of an empty `<div>`, and you reference a [ngTemplate](https://angular.io/guide/structural-directives#the-ng-template) as the else condition.

```html
<table class = "gfg" *ngFor="let product of products; let  a = index;"> 
  <tr> 
      <td class = "geeks">
        <ng-container *ngIf="imagMap.get(product.id) == null; else productImage">
              <img src="./assets/semimagem.png" class="imgTable img-fluid" alt="">
        </ng-container>
        <ng-template #productImage>
              <img [src]="imagMap.get(product.id)" class="imgTable img-fluid">
        </ng-template>
      </td> 
  </tr> 
</table>
```

You can also use a logical **OR**:

```html
<table class = "gfg" *ngFor="let product of products; let  a = index;"> 
  <tr> 
      <td class = "geeks">
         <img [src]="imagMap.get(product.id) || './assets/semimagem.png'" class="imgTable img-fluid">
      </td> 
  </tr> 
</table>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this for the default image:

`<img src="assets/semimagem.png" class="imgTable img-fluid" alt="">`

and `semiagem.png` should be available in the assets folder.

```
<table class = "gfg" *ngFor="let product of products; let  a = index;"> 
  <tr> 
      <td class = "geeks">
          <div *ngIf="imagMap.get(product.id) == null">
              <img src="assets/semimagem.png" class="imgTable img-fluid" alt="">
            </div>
        <img [src]="imagMap.get(product.id)" *ngif="imagMap.get(product.id) !== null" class="imgTable img-fluid">
      </td> 
  </tr> 
</table>
```

Comment: Here the problem is that the product has no image and only the default image should appear, ie the first image of the photo. It is presenting me the default and the other as nonexistent (this should not appear, because when there is no image, it only defaults)

Answer (score 1):

You can are showing the image no matter what. You need to show it only when the default image is not present. You can modify the code as follows

```
<table class = "gfg" *ngFor="let product of products; let  a = index;"> 
  <tr> 
      <td class = "geeks">
          <div *ngIf="imagMap.get(product.id) == null; else nonDefault">
              <img src="./assets/semimagem.png" class="imgTable img-fluid" alt="">
            </div>
        <ng-template #nonDefault>
            <img [src]="imagMap.get(product.id)" class="imgTable img-fluid">
        </ng-template>
      </td> 
  </tr> 
</table>
```

Read about ng if else [Here](https://angular.io/api/common/NgIf)

Answer (score 1):

```
<table class = "gfg" *ngFor="let product of products; let  a = index;"> 
  <tr> 
      <td class = "geeks">
        <ng-template #productImage>
              <img [src]="imagMap.get(product.id) != null 
 ? imagMap.get(product.id) :./assets/semimagem.png" class="imgTable img-fluid">
        </ng-template>
      </td> 
  </tr> 
</table>
```

***Or  Other Way***

```
<table class = "gfg" *ngFor="let product of products; let  a = index;"> 
  <tr> 
      <td class = "geeks">
        <ng-template #productImage>
              <img [src]="imagMap.get(product.id) 
 ? imagMap.get(product.id) : ./assets/semimagem.png" class="imgTable img-fluid">
        </ng-template>
      </td> 
  </tr> 
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this way

`<img [attr.src]="imagMap.get(product.id)?imagMap.get(product.id):defaultImage" />`

in your typescript `defaultImage: any = 'assets/semimagem.png';`

Here `imagMap.get(product.id)` should return value or null